# Cascade geometry in QCL (Quantum Cascade Laser)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, laser

My question is related to one of the online presentation. You can download it from here: http://www.clarity-fp7project.eu/phocadownload/clarity%20tutorials%20qcls.pps

It's written on one of the slides showing cascade scheme of QCL that "Potential to **decrease** the population inversion in each stage. Reduced electron-electron scattering and thus of distribution broadening"

Could someone explain that sentence to me in more Layman's term. I don't see the correlation between cascade geometry of QCL and "potential to decrease the population inversio (..)" Anyway as far as I know, the potentially decrease in the population inversion would be a disadvantage (in this case cascading scheme yields to worse performance due to decrease of population inversion? That's how I interpret that sentence, but still I don't know why it's that.

Comment: Layman's question: QCL stands for ...?

Comment: QCL stands for Quantum Cascade Laser